# getting data from google finance stock screener using r package xml

Tags: xml, r

I want to get the data from the table of [Google finance stock screener](https://www.google.com/finance#stockscreener) into an r dataframe. I tried it out with the xml package in r.

I used the following code:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
URL <- getURL("https://www.google.com/finance#stockscreener")
table <- readHTMLTable(URL, header = TRUE)
table
```

but get an error "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

Is there a way to obtain the table using XML in r. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: What region are you in?  The code works fine for me.

Comment: I 'm from region Belgium. The code works now, but don't gives the expected result

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because your URL is a HTTPS link. In any case, to use RCurl you need the API of the website you're trying to access. It seems the Google Finance API is no longer available. See [this past question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040954/alternative-to-google-finance-api) for alternatives.

Comment: Thanks Philippe for the answer. The API is still available, but i cannot get the data in the format i want. The application seems to be protected.

Comment: Which API are you trying to use?